# fingerprint sensor driver in Linux

Tags: linux

i am considering moving from windows to linux and my labtop is hp pavillion x360 with fingerprint sensor i would like to ask is there any drivier in linux that might operate it ?

and is this driver installable in all distrbutions or only on specific dists ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will likely have to see if the Linux distribution you choose has the driver you need. I did not see one at hp.com (and indeed not either for my X1 with fingerprint at lenovo.com).   https://support.hp.com/in-en/product/HP-Pavilion-13-x360-Convertible-PC-series/8499316/model/9092788/document/c03785459/

Comment: yeah thats why i considered asking here before i move to linux because i definitely don't want to lose features there

Comment: Two options.  (1) find a Linux distribution with the features  OR  (2) what I do:  Run my Linux of choice (Kali and Ubuntu) in a Virtual Machine. Very good on a fast machine with a fast NVMe SSD drive.

Comment: the problem is that windows is slow when i open my IDEs like android studio and vs cod and now i opened my parrot os in live mode and every thing seems to be great but the sensor isn't working i think